# PostgreSQL: How to implement GIN?

Tags: c, postgresql, indexing

I want to bring my text hash function into GIN indexer.

See the Extensibility below:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/gin-extensibility.html

I can understand about **compare**.

```
int compare(Datum a, Datum b)
```

However how about **extractValue**, **extractQuery** and **consistent**.

```
Datum *extractValue(Datum inputValue, int32 *nkeys)

Datum *extractQuery(Datum query, int32 *nkeys, StrategyNumber n, bool **pmatch, Pointer **extra_data)

bool consistent(bool check[], StrategyNumber n, Datum query, int32 nkeys, Pointer extra_data[], bool *recheck)
```

The manual doesn't help me to implement them.

I know how to implement them. In detail:

- What's passed to *inputValue* of **extractValue**?
- What's returned by **extractValue**?
- What's passed to *query* of **extractQuery**?
- What's returned by **extractQuery**?
- What's passed to *query* of **consistent**?
- What's passed to *check* of **consistent**?

The index storage (hashed key) will be **int4**. The input type is **text**.

Comment: This probably ought to be asked directly on the pg-hackers list.

Comment: [pgsql-hackers](http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/)? It is new idea that I had not noticed!

Answer (score 1):

Did you read all the documentation? Do you know what a inverse index does. I can't answer your question fully because you haven't specified what your queries will look like. But here is an attempt (based on the information at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/gin-extensibility.html and http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/Gin). Also, look at the tsearch example.

Input to `compare` is two keys values, so two integers.

The input to `extractValue` is your input type, text. The output is an array of keys: in your case apparently an array of integers.

`extractQuery` gets as input your query type, which might be a string (you don't specify) and returns a list of interesting keys you want the system to find matches for. It can also return extra information for the `consistant` method.

After the system has found values that are interesting according to what you returned from `extractQuery`, this method will return whether the value actually matched the query.

Since you haven't specified your query type I'll give an example with fulltext search.
There for example, the query type is a string like 'foo and bar', this would return the keys 'foo' and 'bar' and some data so the `consistant` function knows that both terms must be present.

But really, this is all described on the above pages.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
For stackoverflow users, the discussion starts here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201307070059.r670xw8F028361@mail.digitaldolphins.jp
I'll post an answer that I want to know by my question, later.